# Django: Validation error only raised when posting from the browser, but not raised from testcases

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF to write a ciphertext encryption/decryption API, and I have run into a weird problem. I have defined one of my models like so:

```
class Key(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='keys')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    alphabet = models.TextField(default=string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits)
```

The serializer for this model (I have omitted a few methods which are irrelevant to the issue):

```
class KeySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Key
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'alphabet', 'content', 'name')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        alphabet = attrs.get('alphabet')
        if alphabet and len(alphabet) > len(set(alphabet)):
            raise ValidationError({'alphabet': 'This field should not contain repeated characters.'})
        alphabet = alphabet or Key._meta.get_field('alphabet').default
        if not all(map(lambda x: x in alphabet, attrs.get('content'))):
            raise ValidationError({'content': 'Invalid characters were provided.'})
        data = dict()
        if 'name' in attrs:
            data['name'] = attrs['name']
        if 'alphabet' in attrs:
            data['alphabet'] = attrs['alphabet']
        if 'content' in attrs:
            data['content'] = attrs['content']

        return data
```

Finally, the view for posting and listing `Key`'s:

```
class KeyList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = KeySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Key.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

The problem that I have encountered is that when I try to post a key through the browser, with an empty string for the `alphabet` attribute, like so:

```
{ 
    "alphabet": ""
    "content": "foobar"
}
```

I get the following response:

```
{ 
    "alphabet": ['This field may not be blank.']
}
```

which is, of course, the desired behaviour. *However*, when I post the same thing from a test case or from the shell, I get this:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:53)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
>>>
>>> client = Client()
>>> client.login(username='password', password='username')
True
>>>
>>> response = client.post(reverse('key-list'), data={'alphabet': '', 'content':'guacamole'})
>>> response.data
{'name': u'', 'url': u'http://testserver/myapp/keys/8/', 'alphabet': u'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789', 'content': u'guacamole', 'id': 1}
```

That is, the validation error is not raised when I post from a test case or shell. Why is this so?

I should also note that the same problem does not occur when I try to post an empty string for the `content` attribute. This makes me suspect that it has something to do with `alphabet` being a `TextField`, but I don't know how to explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alphabet field has a default, so when you save directly through the model, the model accepts a blank and replaces it with a default. When you use the shell you trigger **model validation**.

With the browser, you trigger another validation, that require a field, and fails.

The error is this:

```
alphabet = alphabet or Key._meta.get_field('alphabet').default
```

It does not return the proper default as the model does.

Comment: That line doesn't actually change the validated data in the serializer though, it's just used for validating the `content`. When I return `data`, it contains the version of `alphabet` that was in `attrs`.

Comment: Ok, so the validation of a required field fails, with no defaults, before it gets to the model.